# JQGrid edit form dropdown populated from database

Tags: linq, forms, jqgrid, drop-down-menu, edit

My edit form requires a dropdown to be populated by a database call. I realize I must set the dataurl parm in the colModel. Does anyone have an example using a linq to sql call which returns the data in the format the jqgrid is looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [jqGrid for ASP.NET](http://www.trirand.net/).

Comment: Yes - I did get it to work eventually - although thanks for the link - i'll check it out.